# Java , Matlab reading Data in Wav File , How it differs?

Tags: java, matlab, audio, endianness

At Matlab it seems very very easy but once i try with java read Wav file i get wrong data compared with Matalb

I know that from 44 byte address at the Wav File, that is the actual data

With Matlab i just type this

```
[nData] = wavread("DoorBell.wav",'native')
```

And i have say "133,000" Samples
This is portion from sample number 3000 ~ 3015 :

```
6743 5754 4200 2396 654 -1253 -3141 -4393 -5063 -5062 -4139 -2891 -1588 -193 482
```

> Because there is 2 channel the second channel appear too at matlab with the same values

But one i try to use Java Code to read the Data, It differs I know that WAV saving data into little endian bytes

By this snippet i decide how much bytes i have to read and then read it into byte[] array, and using shortBuffer, and byteBuffer to make it like int16 samples

```
dataBuffer = new byte[getDataBytes(subChunk2Size)];

        //get the actual data
        randAccess.seek(44);
        randAccess.read(dataBuffer);
        System.out.println(dataBuffer.length);

private static short[] bytesToShort(byte[] bytes) 
{
     short[] tempArr = new short[bytes.length/2];
     ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(tempArr);
     return tempArr;
}
short[] samples = bytesToShort(dataBuffer);

for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
            out.println(samples[i]);
        }
```

Here's samples from 3000 to 3015 , " Notice i don't take first samples as an example because it's zero

> 22298 31254 26640 23561 -29182 7163 -17421 -10258 14828 15084 -10769 -18956 -13063 16383 -7679

i am spending a lot of hours try to figure out what is that ?
I dunno !

Comment: If you know that WAV saves data in little-endian format, why are you using `BIG_ENDIAN` in your code?

Comment: 6743 in hex is 0x1a57. 22298 in hex is 0x571a. hmmmm...

Comment: @LukeWoodward

You are Right, it seems my fault, i thought that using BIG_ENDIAN will convert Little to big , Thanks, i did it!
But here another problem, no i have an array with all samples, try to write it to file , but in the file i don't have all samples even i am looping over the array to print all samples to file

Comment: @AhmedAdel: if you have something else to ask, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

WAV format is typically  16 bits per sample - these details are in the headers values which you are evidently not parsing !   so a single 16 bit sample is stored in files as two bytes - hence the need to get your endianness correct.  I would start by defining a single constant, say in floating point 0.6   then convert this into your 16 bit singed integer using both languages. Confirm it works by converting back into float again to assure you get your original 0.6 float.   Once mastered, this side exercise my be very enlightening.

Comment: I did, i know that my particular file Bits per Sample is int16, and i started reading the actual data from address 44 byte where the data start